# Text-shadow not working for Font Awesome icons in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, font-awesome

The text-shadow attribute isn't working in IE10 when applied to Font Awesome icons. I'm not sure if this is per the specs IE10 implements or some other factor.

Using IE10, what CSS property do I need to use to display a shadow like webkit-based browsers do? If using CSS isn't an option, is there another way to achieve a shadow on a Font Awesome icon in IE10?

Example of issue: http://jsfiddle.net/vRqu5/1/

CSS

```
.icon-star-empty {
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 0px 3px rgb(159, 92, 74);
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 3px rgb(159, 92, 74);
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #ffe200;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the same declaration also for `::before` (I don't know if IE10 behaves correctly but at least it works now):

```
.icon-star-empty::before {
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 3px rgb(159, 92, 74);
}
```

Comment: Chased this bug for too long. Nice fix!